# If an identity function is its own inverse then why are its domain and co-domain the same at the same time?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just to clarify, I mean that if an identity function is its own inverse, then doesn't that suggest its domain and co-domain (the same set) are different at different times, even if they're the same set. What is the rule which says that if I map the natural numbers to the natural numbers via the identity function, that the domain and co-domain are the same? Can't I say that I'm instantiating two different versions of the same set, and that I'm mapping id(x) in the domain to element x in the co-domain? Then when I invert the function, the first and second version of the set switch around?

I think I understand the mathematics behind identity and invertible functions, but maybe this is something more fundamental and philosophical in set theory which I'm missing.

Comment: What exactly is a "version of a set" in your optics? Are there e.g. different versions of empty set $\varnothing$ in your optics? If so then please explain. Also in what sense is "different times" a mathematical issue?

Comment: what do you mean? at time x the value is x. if you invert it, at time x the value is x. what do you mean with different at different times? yes, you can say that. but mapping id(x) to x just means mapping x to x.

Comment: NO; they are the same set used twice.

Comment: I want an intuition about what sets are. 
Are they:
1. A nominal description of a real universe/collection instantiated in the usage?
2. The real universe/collection at hand
3. A persuasive device describing a non-real universe/collection, which, through the abstract culture of mathematics, most often refers to what we want it to refer to in the mind of a reader. 

Because I wonder if we can have the sentence "A = A", then why not just "A". 
If we have "A ∪ A", then why not just "A"? 
It's pretty pedantic, but sometimes it feels like math badly mixes together nominalism and platonism.

Comment: You should ask another question for the "intuition" about sets and other stuff about philosophy of mathematicis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not know much about the many set-theories that exist, the generally accepted one (Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory) is axiomatic, and what constitutes a set is not decided by a definition but by axioms. In particular, there is an axiom stating that a set is identified by its elements. So two instances of the same set (as you put it), are in-fact the same set.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very helpful answer.

Comment: @JaydenRivers I am glad it was helpful :) and for the sake of reopening your question, I will add the reasons why some might find it unclear: While the question is clear (to me) in what follows the first sentence and your comment about the intuition of what sets are; the first sentence and the title seem a bit different, and I will explain how in a separate comment.

Comment: Think of the identity map on $X$ as $i: A \rightarrow B$, where $A$ is $X$ but as the domain and $B$ is $X$ but as the co-domain. Saying that it is its own inverse means $i=i^{-1}$ where $i^{-1}:B \rightarrow A$, and we see that it actually suggests that $A$ and $B$ are the same since they are both the domain of the same function, contrary to what the first sentence says.